# Add button inside a notebook tab

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-9, odoo-10

[image]How to add a button inside a notebook tab before one2many field?
for example, I want to add a button in a notebook tab before one2many field.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello Gautam Bothra,**

## Solution

Try this below code,

```
<page string="Tab_Name">
    <group>
        <button type="object" name="Python_Method_Name" string="Button_Name" />
        <field name="one2Many_Field_Name">
            <tree>
                <field name="name" string="name" />
            </tree>

        </field>
    </group>
</page>
```

If any query so comment please.
I hope my answer is helpful.

Comment: hello mayur, it is not working. I have added my code please suggest if any error.

Comment: Which error are you get please specify. Because it's smoothly work for me..

Comment: are you add your all details in my code like Tab_Name, Python_Method_Name, Button_Name...etc

Comment: It is not any error but the button is not visible in the notebook tab. I have added code above.

Answer (score 0):

Add the button field within "group" tag before your one2many field.

```
<notebook>
    <page string="New Tab">
    <group>
        <button type="object" name="btnMethod" string="btnName" />
    </group>
    <field name="field_ids">
        <tree editable="bottom" string="Product" create="0">
        <field name="name"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Regards